# tvOS 9.1 UITableView header view does not float

Tags: uitableview, tvos, tvos9.1

Can't achieve default UITableView headers sticky behaviour. Already tried plain and group tableview style. Can U please help me with advice in which way I have to dig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table view section headers aren't sticky for tvOS. However, sticky headers in collection views work.

Comment: Is it still like this? I need the stationary behavior for the header actually.

Comment: I think you can try set up your collection view to look alike table view to achieve appearance you need with the sticky behaviour